A non-self-intersecting unit side length polygon in a unit square has odd number of sides unless it is the square itself
This is the same question as here in MO.
I have a conjecture, it is like this:

Suppose there is a non-self-intersecting polygon lies inside a closed square of length $1$. The polygon has every side length of $1$. Suppose the polygon is not the boundary of the unit square (i.e. a square frame.) Prove or disprove that the number of sides of the polygon is on odd number.

I have pondered this problem for quite a while. What I have tried is this: Suppose the unit square is dissected into four $1/2\times 1/2$ quadrants, like $\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline1 & 2\\\hline3&4\\\hline\end{array}$. Therefore, we want to prove that the line segments that go through the quadrants diagonally ($1$ to $4$, or $2$ to $3$) is odd number. To prove this, I want to prove the intermediate steps:
(1) We don't have both kinds of diagonals. That is, no edges from $1$ to $4$ and $2$ to $3$.
(2) All the diagonal-crossing segments are together.
(3) The diagonal crossing segment has odd number of them.
However, I stuck at all of them... Is there a way to solve this problem (even if not using the ideas from above)? Any help are welcome!
P.S. we can construct the polygon as this for $2k+1$ sides, as the zigzag shape:

The square of size $1$ is the smallest possible, because we can have this shape for any square $1+\varepsilon$: we have the edges as the original square's edge and have a spike inside.


@CalvinLin What I mean is the polygon is not a square. I kind of abuse the term ''square'' as the closed region and as the frame. I haven't thought about this  phrasing before, but I do not know what to change to either.

Square means something specific. Perhaps you mean four sided polygon, or something like that?

@MathieuRundström No, I really mean the sides of the square... I have edited the question as Calvin Lin pointed out. Sorry for the confusion.

@CalvinLin Sorry, I just found out that is my mistake... What I mean is the closed shape, but you're right, to write in your way is more clear. I thought you mean something in the title.

Your intermediate steps seem difficult to prove, if true at all. It's also not clear to me what you even mean by the second one. For the first one, there are definitely chains of unit length segments that contain both types of diagonals. I'm not sure if there are closed chains though, i.e. polygons.

@Servaes Yeah, so that's why I was stuck at there because generally, you can put two line segments with 1, 4 and 2, 3 of units lehgth without intersection. (I remember in my MO post I have written this.) For the second one, let's say you only have. diagonal segments 1, 4. Then all the 1, 4 segment are connected, i.e. You can not have something (the region of the end points) like 2 1 4 1 4 3 4 ... 2 1 4 1 4 ...

To me, a more viable approach would seem to divide the square into 9 regions, by the quarter-circles centered at the corners of the square. Then such a polygon cannot have any vertices in the center region, and any vertices in the corner regions severely restrict the shape of the polygons. A lot of casework though.

@Servaes That's a nice idea! I am looking forward for your answer!
